# How to handle downloads with GTK WebKit?

Tags: c++, webkit, gtkmm

I'm stuck with an issue that I'm gonna try and explain clearly. I'm using a **gtkmm webkit browser** in a sort of embedded application to access php/html files. The point is that **I fail to code a way for this webkit to handle downloads**.

Oh, and I'm coding in C++.

The file to download currently looks like below in my HTML code :

```
<a href='excel/template_users.php'><img src='imgs/excelbis.png'/>Download Excel File</a>
```

The "template_users.php" file is just a way of forcing the user to download the file (you can also access to the website via a "classic" web browser). It contains only :

```
<?php
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=template_users.xls");
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel:");
    readfile("template_users.xls");
?>
```

I've been trying to handle downloads by adding to my IntegratedBrowser class constructor (which instantiate the webkit) a connector to the signal "download-requested" :

```
gboolean ret = FALSE;
g_signal_connect(webView, "download-requested", G_CALLBACK(&IntegratedBrowser::downloadRequested), &ret);
```

And the associated method :

```
gboolean IntegratedBrowser::downloadRequested(WebKitWebView* webView, WebKitDownload *download, gboolean *handled)
{
    const gchar* dest = webkit_download_get_uri(download);
    webkit_download_set_destination_uri(download, dest);
   return FALSE;
}
```

I should precise that everything runs of course fine when I'm trying to download the file via a "classic web browser". The c++ code compile smoothly, however, nothing happens when I click on the link using the webkit. I would like the file to be downloaded in a location chosen by the user if possible (downloading the file into a specific location is viable as well) when clicking on the link.

Have you got any idea of what I am doing incorrectly ?

Thanks for your answers !

Edit : now my downloadRequested method looks like that :

```
gboolean IntegratedBrowser::downloadRequested(WebKitWebView* webView, WebKitDownload *download, gboolean *handled)
{
    const gchar* dest = g_strdup_printf("%s", "file:///home/user/test.xls");
    webkit_download_set_destination_uri(download, dest);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return FALSE` from your `IntegratedBrowser::downloadRequested()` method cancels the download. `return TRUE` should start it.

Also, you are getting the URI that you are downloading with `webkit_download_get_uri()` (e.g. `http://my.website.com/myfile.jpeg`) and setting that to be the destination URI. Set the destination URI to point to a local file instead (although leaving it unset probably downloads the file to a default location.)

If you want a file selector for choosing where to save the download, use [`GtkFileChooser`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html) and when you are done with it, retrieve a URI using [`gtk_file_chooser_get_uri()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-get-uri).

Comment: Thank you ptomato for this answer. Unfortunately I did try that before (but I gave it one more since you suggested it) and nothing's happening. 

Should the webkit_download_get_uri command prompt a pop up asking for the download location of the file ?

Comment: No, make sure to [read the documentation](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitdownload.html#webkit-download-get-uri) to find out what it does. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. At least it's way more clear in my head now ! Unfortunately, the code based on your suggestions (edited at the end of my question) still doesn't work.
The only clue I have is, given the [documentation](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-download-requested) of the download-requested signal, that no signal is emitted because of the MIME type of the (excel) file I'm trying to download. Could that be it ?

Comment: Guess I'll "just" look into that now :)

Thanks once again for this precious answers !